# How to get name of the day from dosamigos datepicker in yii2?

Tags: php, datepicker, yii2, dayofweek

This is my coding for the datepicker. i want to get the name of the day when user select the date from the datepicker. Please i'm new to this and i need to complete this for my final year project. Thank you in advance.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'appDate')->widget(
        DatePicker::className(), [
             'inline' => false, 
            'clientOptions' => [
                'autoclose' => true,
                'format' => 'yyyy-m-d'
            ]
]);?>
```

Comment: What's going wrong with what you have?

Comment: the coding work well without error. i just want to ask how should i do to get the name of the day and display it from the date selected from the datepicker ?

Comment: Did you look at the manual for the code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to use events to get selected date to get day name.
I used `changeDate` event,
here is code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'appDate')->widget(
    DatePicker::className(), [
        'inline' => false, 
        'clientOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-m-d',
        ],
        'clientEvents' => [
            'changeDate' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(e){var days =["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
                $("#dayname").text(days[e.date.getDay()]); }') ,
        ] ,
    ]);?>
```

I created an element for showing day name:

```
<span id="dayname"></span>
```

For put into your input:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'appDate')->widget(
    DatePicker::className(), [
        'inline' => false, 
        'clientOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-m-d',
        ],
        'clientEvents' => [
            'changeDate' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(e){var days =["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
                $("#appointment-appday").val(days[e.date.getDay()]); }') ,
        ] ,
    ]);?>
```

Comment: sir, can i know how to put the "dayname" inside this :                                         <?= $form->field($model, 'appDay')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

Comment: you need to find appDay input id and replace with $("#dayname").

Comment: for find id, after run project you can find in inspect element

Comment: how can i make change to the code inside the inspect element ? i'm not found any file like my inspect elements to change  the input id

Comment: this is the code in the inspect element : <input type="text" id="appointment-appday" class="form-control" name="Appointment[appDay]" maxlength="10" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">